# How do electrons flow in a "random single wire antenna" of a Raspberry Pi, which is DC and just have one path? (no gnd)

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, electronics, electrical-engineering, antennas

I have been amazed by the fact that just by inserting a cable in a [GPIO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_input/output) of the raspberry pic acts like an antenna, as far as I know, electromagnetic waves are generated when there's current, and also, there's only current when a circuit is closed, but this seems "open" to me, like, how are the actual waves generated?
Also, this works with DC, right? So makes even harder for me to understand that wave generation.

[image]

Comment: Look at the Wikipedia article [Dipole antenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole_antenna) and imagine that half the dipole has been removed and that end of the resistor has been earthed  There is a  very good animation to help one understand what is going on.

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Some comments removed. Friendly reminder: to answer a question, please post an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 1):

That circuit (a "long wire antenna") is indeed open *at DC conditions* but at *ultrahigh frequencies* it is not; an impinging UHF EM wave will induce AC currents all along the length of the wire even though its far end is not connected to anything. The signal induced in the long wire simply has to obey its boundary condition constraints which means at the tip of the antenna, the current is identically zero. you can think of those currents as the electrons "sloshing" back and forth along the length of the wire like water in a bucket.

Comment: Re, "...like water in a bucket." Another good image might be longitudinal waves on a  stretched-out [Slinky™](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slinky). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIkeGBXqWW0

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but, this would be in the case of the antenna receiving a wave, right? I think I understood your answer, but in this case, being the antenna an emitter, works the same way?

Comment: Yes yes, antennas exhibit a property called reciprocity which means they behave similarly as both emitters and receivers.

Comment: @nielsnielsen so, I understood how an impinging UHF EM wave will "shake" the wire and generate AC currents, but, in the other way, when we want to emit? there's not that EM wave generating the current, so how we generate the wave itself?